# Improving filepath search in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, unix, search, full-text-search

I have several million filenames I need to search through. They look like this:

```
LG_MARGINCALL_HD2CH_127879834_EN.mov
```

If someone searches for any of the following, it should match:

- margin
- margin call
- margin call mov
- margin call hd en
- margin call hd en mov

What I am currently using is a mysql %LIKE% search. Something like:

```
SELECT filename FROM path WHERE filename LIKE '%margin%' AND filename LIKE '%mov%'
```

It is deathly slow (can take up to ten seconds for a search). Note that it **does work** though.

What would be a better way to do the above search? Either using mysql or another program.

Comment: Will users search by filename, by film title, or both?

Comment: They will be searching both.

Comment: I would advice having a look at Lucene which caters this kind of searches extremely well.

Comment: Sounds like a new bittorrent service :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your search strategy is, as you noticed, slow. It's slow because

```
 LIKE '%something%'
```

has to scan the table to find matches. Leading % signs on `LIKE` searches are an excellent way to wreck performance.

I don't know how many columns are in your `path` table.  If there are a *lot of columns* you could do two quick things to improve performance:

1. get rid of `SELECT *` and list the names of the columns you want in your resultset.
2. create a compound index consisting of your `filename` column followed by the other columns you need to retrieve.

(This won't help if you only have a few columns in your table.)

You can't use straight-out-of-the-software-package `FULLTEXT` searching for this stuff, because that's designed for language text.

If I had to make this work fast for production, I would do this:

First, create a new table called "searchterm" containing

```
 filename_id INT   the id number of a row in your path table
 searchterm  VARCHAR(20)  a fragment of a filename.
```

Second, write a program that reads the `filename_id` and `filename` values, and inserts a bunch of different rows for each one into `searchterm`. For the item you've shown the values should be:

```
LG_MARGINCALL_HD2CH_127879834_EN.mov   (original)
LG  MARGINCALL  HD2CH  127879834  EN  mov   (split on punctuation)
 HD 2 CH                                    (split on embedded numerics)
 MARGIN CALL                                (split on an app-specific list of words)
```

So, you'd have a bunch of entries in your searchterm table, all with the same `filename_id` value and lots of different little chunks of text.

Finally, when searching you could do this.

```
 SELECT path.id, path.filename, path.whatever,
        COUNT(DISTINCT searchterms.term) AS termcount
   FROM path
   JOIN searchterm ON path.filenanme_id = search.filename_id
  WHERE searchterm.term  IN ('margin','call','hd','en', 'mov')
  GROUP BY path.id, path.filename, path.whatever
  ORDER BY path.filename, COUNT(DISTINCT searchterms.term) DESC
```

This little query finds all the matching fragments to what you're search for. It returns multiple file names, and it presents them in order of what matches the most terms.

What I'm suggesting is that you create your own application-specific kinda- sorta- full text search system.  If your really have several million multimedia files, this is surely worth your effort.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I like the idea above, but am having trouble figuring out how we would do something like 'app-specific' splitting of keywords, such as a movie title: margincall --> margin call. We don't really know all the movie names based on the file (and often it might be abbreviated). Would there be a way to do something like a %LIKE% serach on the title alone?

Comment: In any Linux or *nix distribution there's a free (free as in kittens, free as in speech) file full of common words. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix) . You might be able to use that file to help break up phrases like MARGINCALL in useful ways.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, and I think would work well for English titles. What about for foreign titles? For example: ABRESUSOJOS_HD.mov (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Your_Eyes_(1997_film)).

Comment: Some possible sources:  http://www.freedict.org/en/  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/  I think these will be a little harder to use than the english word list.

Comment: @user1436531, for foreign titles breaking into words is tough, and things are complicated by diacritics (é, ü... -> e, ue...) and ligatures (æ, ß..., ae, ss...), which may be "normalized to English" or not

Comment: I just implemented this method -- it is actually SLOWER that using the like query. I imagine because joining on two million-record tables.

Comment: Have you optimized it yet? Have you done `EXPLAIN` on your queries? Have you tried a compound covering index on `searchterm (term, filename_id)`?

Comment: At a minimum, index searchterm.term.

Answer (score 3):

It seems clear that you need **full-text search** functionality.

There are multiple solutions out there that can respond to this, one of the best at the moment being **[Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)**.

It has all the capabilities to handle real time full-text search.
And it goes largely beyond just this by providing auto-suggestions, autocomplete, etc.

And it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using like statement instead use match() and use a full text index for your searching column and your table must be a MYISAM one(I don't know whether it is or not)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2 things to try for better performance. The 1st one is to use keyword [EXPLAIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) in front of `select`. This may gives you some help about the slow performance of the query. But I think it will not do much help. The 2nd thing is to use [REGEXP](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/). An example of all these:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT filename FROM path WHERE filename LIKE REGEXP '^.*MAR{1}.*mov{1}'
```

but you have to search a little more to optimize the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SPHINX for fulltext search.
http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster than using `AND`:

```
SELECT filename FROM path WHERE filename LIKE '%margin%call%hd%en%mov%'
```

But having a "%" in the start of the string will always make it slow.

You should use a full-text search index on the field, and then use something like:

```
SELECT filename FROM path WHERE MATCH(filename) AGAINST('+margin +call +hd +en +mov' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```